# How to show AdMob Interstitial one time on back button tap

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have this code:

```
func createAndLoadInterstitial()  {
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.loadRequest(request)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if (interstitial.isReady && showAd) {
        showAd = false
        // print("iterstitialMain is ready")
        interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        self.createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
    else {
        showAd = true
    }
}
```

and it works. But it shows an ad every time the user taps on the back button.

I want to show an ad only one time when the user taps on the back button. Would it be better to show an ad after some time instead? For example, every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you setting `showAd` to `true` initially? The logic in your `if` statement is the main issue.

After you set `showAd = false` in your `if` statement, the next time `viewDidAppear` is called your `else` statement will be executed, setting `showAd` back to `true`.

What you should do is check your `Bool`, and then check `interstitial.isReady`. Then, in your `GADInterstitial`'s `interstitialDidDismissScreen` delegate method you would update your `showAd` `Bool` and request another `GADInterstitial` if you'd like. You say you only want to show one `GADInterstitial` so requesting another is not necessary. For example:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if showAd { // Should we show an ad?
        if interstitial.isReady { // Is the ad ready?
            interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        }
    }
    else {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    // Ad was presented and dismissed
    print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
    showAd = false // Don't show anymore ads
}
```

Also, you can change:

```
let request = GADRequest()
interstitial.loadRequest(request)
```

to just:

```
interstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest())
```

in your `createAndLoadInterstitial` function.

To answer the second part of your question asking if you should present an ad after some time delay, that is a violation of the AdMob program policies.

Examples of non-compliant implementations:

> - Interstitial ads that appear before the app has opened or after the    app has closed.
> - Interstitial ads that are triggered after a user closes another interstitial ad.
> - Interstitial ads loading unexpectedly while a user is viewing the app’s content. Remember to only serve interstitials between pages of content.
> - Interstitial ads that trigger after every user click.
> - Interstitial ads that appear during periods of game play or heavy user interaction.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot.